# systemctl minecraft server failing with no error log

Tags: ubuntu, java, systemd, minecraft, systemctl

Question was originally asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748821/systemctl-minecraft-server-failing-with-no-error-log?noredirect=1#comment121498826_68748821) but was moved when it was suggested that I post on superuser instead.

I'm running a Minecraft server off a VPS running Ubuntu. The server is run through systemctl and runs well for the most part, but randomly it will crash with result code `signal`. The VPS has 16gb of ram so that shouldn't be the issue as afar as I'm aware.

Here's the status:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minecraft@.service; disabled;
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2021-08-11 15:27:54 CDT; 2min 52>
    Process: 347348 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx14G -Xms14G -jar forge-1.12.2-1>
   Main PID: 347348 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 19148)
     Memory: 4.1G
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-minecraft.slice/minecraft@server.service
```

The server doesn't produce a crash report, which leads me to believe this is a systemctl issue and not a minecraft crash. Here's my systemd file for the minecraft@server.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Nice=1
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx14G -Xms14G -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui -Dfml.queryResult=confirm
ExecStop=/opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon -H 000.000.000.000 -P 31415 -p pass stop


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If any other information is needed I will be quick to provide it.

Comment: Check `dmesg` to see if the OOM killer struck.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the quick reply. I am new to ubuntu, could you tell me what I should look for in this log?

Comment: OOM is “out of memory” so any messages about memory usage right before the crash.  You set the minimum and maximum JVM memory swap to the same size.  Is that optimal in this case? I question that because that service indicates it was only using 4.1 GB when it crashed

Comment: What happens if you run the command line from a prompt directly and get systemctl out of the way? (for troubleshooting of course)  Does it crash then?  Does it provide better console info?